# Making A Graphic Pie Chart In C#

Tags: c#, graphics, pie-chart, slice

I'm trying to write a Windows Application that shows a pie chart with seven unequal slices (25%, 20%, 18%, 17%, 10%, 10%, 10%) all of them will be colored differently.

So far I have made Pens and Brushes with colors attached and drawn a circle.

This is what I have so far

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        this.BackColor = Color.White;
        this.Text = "Pie Chart";
        this.Width = 350;
        this.Height = 350;

        Pen black = new Pen(Color.Black);
        Pen blue = new Pen(Color.Blue);
        Pen green = new Pen(Color.Green);
        Pen red = new Pen(Color.Red);
        Pen orange = new Pen(Color.Orange);
        Pen pink = new Pen(Color.Pink);
        Pen purple = new Pen(Color.Purple);
        Pen magenta = new Pen(Color.Purple);
        Brush brBlue = blue.Brush;
        Brush brGreen = green.Brush;
        Brush brRed = red.Brush;
        Brush brOrange = orange.Brush;
        Brush brPink = pink.Brush;
        Brush brPurple = purple.Brush;
        Brush brMagenta = magenta.Brush;
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;

        g.DrawEllipse(black, 20, 10, 300, 300);

    }
```

My question to you is. What would be the easiest way to draw the wedges of the pie?

Comment: Don't forget to Dispose your GDI+ resources or put them into a Using block.

Comment: This [tutorial](http://forum.codecall.net/csharp-tutorials/7917-tutorial-vs2008-c-pie-chart.html) may be helpful.

Comment: You really put 110% into this one!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I will advise you to take a look at **[ZedGraph](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/zedgraph.aspx)**.

If you want a sample code to actually draw pieChart using GDI you can check this **[tutorial.](http://www.codeguru.com/columns/dotnet/article.php/c6145)**. It uses [**FillPie**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.fillpie%28VS.71%29.aspx) Method of Graphics class.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't a direct answer to you question, but why aren't you using the [Microsoft chart controls](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=130f7986-bf49-4fe5-9ca8-910ae6ea442c&DisplayLang=en)?

[Scott Gu's post about it](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx)

Comment: Because I don't have administrative rights on this computer to install them :)

Comment: You don't need to install them. Just copy the DLLs and reference them in your project.

Answer (score 5):

CodeProject.com has several samples.  [Here's one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/julijanpiechart.aspx) I've used.  Also, I would recommend looking into the [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/).  It will do this for you.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.